# X server on Kubuntu 18.04 crashes if NIS/NFS user is logged in

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, login, 18.04

I updated a machine to Kubuntu 18.04 by a complete reinstall. We still have user management using NFS/NIS. Packages are installed, users can log in. I have one local user `dhlocal` (userid: 1000) with home directory `/localhome/dhlocal` and users like `dh` (userid: 5000) with home dir `/home/dh`.

I can log in `dhlocal` to the X/KDE session and work there without any problems - if only that user is logged in.

If I log in `dh`, the system pauses for some 20 seconds (regardless whether the login is on console or X). Then, KDE comes up. After about two minutes the system suddenly crashes. `.xsession-errors` at the end looks like this:

```
The session is not registered:  "PID 11214 does not belong to any known session"
QObject::connect: No such signal 
QDBusAbstractInterface::PrepareForSleep(bool)
powerdevil: Backend is ready, KDE Power Management system initialized
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-dh'
klauncher: Exiting on signal 15
ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 11236, errno = 32
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Unterbrechung während des Betriebssystemaufrufs) on X server ":0"
      after 37 requests (37 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

The weird thing is: If I log in `dh` on a console (i.e. `Ctrl-Alt-F2` and login) while having `dhlocal` logged in to X/KDE, the `dhlocal` session *also* crashes after some two minutes. This even happens if I log in again `dhlocal` on KDE as long as `dh` is logged in on any console. Messages in `.xsession-errors` of `dhlocal`:

```
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
kdeinit5: sending SIGTERM to children.
kdeinit5: Exit.
klauncher: Exiting on signal 15
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden) on X  server ":0"
      after 3523 requests (3523 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden) on X server ":0"
      after 1122 requests (1122 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("kwin_x11") is still running.
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Unexpected response from KInit (response = 0).
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
startkde: Could not start ksmserver. Check your installation.
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Error: Can't open display: :0
Could not connect to D-Bus server: 
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: 
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-V6z3BsURMt: Verbindungsaufbau 
  abgelehnt
startkde: Shutting down...
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0) failed: : 
No such file or directory
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
xprop:  unable to open display ':0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0'
startkde: Done.
```

I removed the complete environment of `dh` and replaced `.profile`/`.bashrc` with `dhlocal`'s version. I observe two things with `dh`:

. Logging in has this 20+ seconds delay which happens even before any bash startup file in `$HOME` or `/etc` is executed. I do not know where this comes from.

. For some reason, `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not set for `dh`. Other environment variables, however, are. Once again `.xsession-errors` for `dh`:

```
Xsession: X session started for dh at Mo 30. Apr 17:06:17 CEST 2018
localuser:dh being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/tmp/kwallet5_dh.socket
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/plasma.mandatory.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=dh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/plasma.default.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/dh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/dh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/plasma:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/dh/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=dh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-rMq6WSod2U,guid=9e31faa7d68efa98592ebb2b5ae730ea
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PAM_KWALLET_LOGIN=/tmp/kwallet_dh.socket
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/dh/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg:/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kf5-settings
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
```

What's going on here? How can I fix this? Is any further information needed?

Comment: Just as an information for any reader stumbling upon this: I was unable to solve the problem so far. I downgraded the system to Ubuntu 16.04. I will retry somewhen in the future...

Comment: do you wanna give the points to anyone or just sacrifice them to the FSM?